# new PC is blue screening when installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash

I've built quite a few PC's so not entirely inexperienced, but got problem here!
Just built a new PC from new parts which is blue screening on installing Windows 7, after about 5 times I managed to get through the installation, the the OS ran fine most of the time but occassionally blue screened.

I tried swapping out all the ram sticks (I.E just installing with 1, but still no luck, I since swapped out my SSD 80gb for a new Sata drive, but still couldn't get through installation.

I'm trying to figure out which part it could be? So annoying! What do you guys think I should? Next thing I was thinking was to swap out the DVD drive, and then the Motherboard....

Comment: Have a look in the BIOS and make sure that the memory settings reported match what you have installed.

Comment: Read the error message and try to figure out what hardware fault it is reporting.  If you want more than just random flailing around and guesswork from other people, _tell the rest of us the error message_, too.

Answer (score 1):

Do these bluescreens happen at regular intervals, or more frequently at certain times (like when it is formatting the drive), or based on whether the case is all screwed down and buttoned up?

Do you have a RAID controller of some type that would complicate the installation?

Did you use heatsink compound when attaching the HeatSink and CPU?
Did you take that little plastic flap off the CPU before attaching the HeatSink?

Try resetting your bios to the factory options.
Check out the CPU temp in bios.  Make sure it doesn't get too high.

I'd say burn a disc of [knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/) (or some other LiveCD distro).  It has a memory test you can run.  If everything seems to work properly with that, and the memory test works out, it should show if the memory, CPU, DVD drive are all good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the BIOS is up to date.